# R ggplot or other: How can I plot a line of best fit for grouped AND paired data on the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot 5 lines of best fit summarising 5 groups of paired points (i.e. summarising the lines between the two points)

I have a data set structured like this (readings of yield and rainfall for 500 farms grouped into 5 production systems for 2 years. Each farm occurs twice in the data set  2015 and 2017):

```
FARM ID (cocoa$XACIB) // YEAR //  RAINFALL (cocoa$X15_clim) //  YIELD (cocoa$TY_15.1.16_HA) // SYSTEM (cocoa$Production_system)

1   // 2015 //  1200    //  500    //  A

1   // 2017 //  1400    // 600     //  A

2   // 2015 //  900    // 400      //  B
```

Reproducible data set at bottom...

I want to create a scatter plot of RAINFALL (x axis) vs YIELD (y axis) with points grouped by SYSTEM and a line of best fit for each of the 5 SYSTEMS based on the paired change in YIELD for each ID (Farm).

Currently I have got stuck with, generating a graph of paired data but no trendline:

```
ggplot(cocoa, aes(x=cocoa$X15_clim, y=cocoa$TY_15.1.16_HA,  color=cocoa$Production_system)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(group=cocoa$XACIB)
```

paired data with lines but no trendlines
[image: paired data with lines but no trendlines]

or stuck with a graph of grouped data with trendlines for production systems but not baed on the pairs based on all the data for each production system:

```
ggplot(cocoa, aes(x=cocoa$X15_clim, y=cocoa$TY_15.1.16_HA,  color=cocoa$Production_system)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se =FALSE)
```

trend lines for groups but not pairs...
[image: trend lines for groups but not pairs...]

Please could someone help me find a way to produce a trend line for each group based on the paired data?

**MANY THANKS!**

```
dput(cocoa)

structure(list(Production_system = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("A_CONV1", "B_UTZ", "C_ORG", "D_CONV2", "E_RA"), class = "factor"), 
    XACIB = c(22000, 22000, 30000, 30000, 35701, 35701, 42016, 
    42016, 44880, 44880, 46800, 46800, 48000, 48000, 56672, 56672, 
    62119, 62119, 65318.4, 65318.4, 76916, 76916, 79040, 79040, 
    82194, 82194, 85800, 85800, 90576, 90576, 90720, 90720, 92252.8, 
    92252.8, 93728, 93728, 94080, 94080, 105473, 105473, 105600, 
    105600, 108160, 108160, 108820, 108820, 111385.2, 111385.2, 
    112060, 112060, 113568, 113568, 116280, 116280, 119145, 119145, 
    120392, 120392, 128625, 128625, 131040, 131040, 135000, 135000, 
    138256, 138256, 143208, 143208), TY_15.1.16_HA = c(459.6153, 
    306.4102, NA, 905.3028636, NA, 229.80765, 229.80765, 612.8204, 
    NA, 15.95886458, 306.4102, 204.2734667, 344.711475, 689.42295, 
    229.80765, 383.01275, 306.4102, 229.80765, 102.1367333, 153.2051, 
    183.84612, 344.711475, 61.28204, 91.92306, 901.2064706, 1201.608627, 
    919.2306, 766.0255, 536.21785, 153.2051, 265.5555067, 306.4102, 
    NA, 229.80765, 95.7531875, 287.2595625, 510.6836667, 638.3545833, 
    127.6709167, 306.4102, 14.36297813, 153.2051, 612.8204, 1021.367333, 
    383.01275, 510.6836667, 87.54577143, 131.3186571, 200.3451308, 
    223.9151462, 107.24357, 199.16663, 868.1622333, 800.0710778, 
    465.289563, 635.5174519, 932.3624657, 875.4577143, 357.4785667, 
    510.6836667, 255.3418333, 153.2051, 218.8644286, 21.88644286, 
    103.8922084, 146.5023769, 282.8401846, 306.4102), X15_clim = c(1148.415157, 
    1413.089005, 1148.415157, 1413.089005, 1214.720448, 1257.496108, 
    1136.028355, 1383.640551, 1270.817029, 1297.849306, 1270.817029, 
    1297.849306, 1136.028355, 1383.640551, 1244.262682, 1281.788645, 
    1214.136308, 1279.60737, 1244.262682, 1281.788645, 1270.817029, 
    1297.849306, 1118.994984, 1350.821456, 1125.50238, 1370.241065, 
    1136.028355, 1383.640551, 1214.136308, 1279.60737, 1126.707093, 
    1391.304566, 1245.721294, 1307.936407, 1240.241637, 1267.070353, 
    1125.50238, 1370.241065, 1270.817029, 1297.849306, 1094.358686, 
    1346.225715, 1118.994984, 1350.821456, 1214.720448, 1257.496108, 
    1246.361514, 1266.872479, 1245.721294, 1307.936407, 1136.028355, 
    1383.640551, 1118.994984, 1350.821456, 1136.028355, 1383.640551, 
    1136.028355, 1383.640551, 1214.136308, 1279.60737, 1139.349273, 
    1397.517303, 1148.415157, 1413.089005, 1214.720448, 1257.496108, 
    1214.720448, 1257.496108)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-68L))
```

Comment: Can you review the code in your question ? Currently, the code display does not reflect each graph obtained (see x and y axis title)

Comment: Also, please provide a reproducible example of your dataset by following this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example it will help people to assist you

Comment: Ah sorry i changed the code to make it easier to read with the text (first time on here!). Actual code: ggplot(cocoa, aes(x=cocoa$X15_clim, y=cocoa$TY_15.1.16_HA,  color=cocoa$Production_system)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se =FALSE)

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect those changes. It will be easier for people to follow your question without to dig informations into comments section

Comment: First: Your example dataset is not well chosen. It contains only data for one production system and only one obs. per farm. Second: It's an easy task to make a best fit line for each farm. However, if I got you right, you want a line of best fit for each farm by production system, i.e. farms switch production systems?

Comment: Hi @stefan thanks for your response. I have changed the example data set as suggested (apologies first time on here). I would like to make a best fit line per production system - but taking into account that each point (rainfall vs yield) is paired (i.e. there are two points per farm (two years) ) so i want to generate a line of best fit that summarises the yield response to rainfall for each group (production system). Farms do not switch production systems. Many thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I got you right. The trick is to add `group = XACIB` to the set of aesthetics. BTW: As in your first approach you can also switch to `geom_line` instead of `geom_smooth`. Same plot as you have only 2 datapoints per farm. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(cocoa, aes(x = X15_clim, y = TY_15.1.16_HA, color = Production_system, group = XACIB)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing non-finite values (stat_smooth).
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks for this. Actually I am aiming to produce only 5 lines of best fit. 1 per Production system. I expect the plot to look like the second picture I posted (however the problem with that plot is that the lines of best fit are constructed treating each point as individual - where as they are actually paired). This is the problem I want to overcome ...

Comment: Hm. In that case: I have to think about that. (; Sounds like you want do a panel regression with fixed effects, i.e. constant slopes per production system but varying intercepts by farm. Don't know whether this can be achieved via geom_smooth. Probably you have to compute the regression lines manually before plotting.